# What could be the reason that `require` doesn't work in some places?

Tags: require, raku

Loading a module (`ABC`) with `require` works in one module of a distribution while it fails in another module of the distribution. 
What could be the reason that loading `ABC` with `require` fails in one place?

```
require Name::ABC;
my $new = Name::ABC.new(); # dies: You cannot create an instance of this type (ABC)
```

---

```
perl6 -v
This is Rakudo Star version 2019.03.1 built on MoarVM version 2019.03
implementing Perl 6.d.
```

The the required module: [App::DBBrowser::Subqueries](https://github.com/kuerbis/App-DBBrowser-p6/blob/master/lib/App/DBBrowser/Subqueries.pm6)

[App::DBBrowser::Union](https://github.com/kuerbis/App-DBBrowser-p6/blob/master/lib/App/DBBrowser/Union.pm6), line 80: OK *

[App::DBBrowser::Join](https://github.com/kuerbis/App-DBBrowser-p6/blob/master/lib/App/DBBrowser/Join.pm6), lines 66 and 191: OK *

[App::DBBrowser::Table::Extensions](https://github.com/kuerbis/App-DBBrowser-p6/blob/master/lib/App/DBBrowser/Table/Extensions.pm6), line 49: OK *

[App::DBBrowser](https://github.com/kuerbis/App-DBBrowser-p6/blob/master/lib/App/DBBrowser.pm6), line 690:  You cannot create an instance of this type (Subqueries) *

[App::DBBrowser::CreateTable](https://github.com/kuerbis/App-DBBrowser-p6/blob/master/lib/App/DBBrowser/CreateTable.pm6), line 112: You cannot create an instance of this type (Subqueries) *

* version `0.0.1`

Comment: From the looks of the code, it's impossible to know what's the problem here. Can you please show the code for Name::ABC?

Comment: Zoffix and I were also confused about this. See Z's [still open issue "`require Foo;` does not replace `package` with proper class"](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1865) and my comment on ugexe's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ cat XXX.rakumod
unit class XXX;

$ cat ZZZ.rakumod
module ZZZ {
    require XXX;
    XXX.new;
    say "OK";
}

$ raku -I. -e 'use ZZZ;'
===SORRY!===
You cannot create an instance of this type (XXX)
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules.html#require):

> require loads a compunit and imports definite symbols at runtime.

You are doing a runtime load of a module while also expecting the symbols for that module to exist at compile time. Instead you should use indirect name lookup (as shown at the bottom of the documentation page linked earlier):

```
$ cat XXX.rakumod
unit class XXX;

$ cat ZZZ.rakumod
module ZZZ {
    require XXX;
    ::("XXX").new;
    say "OK";
}

$ raku -I. -e 'use ZZZ;'
OK
```

Comment: "You are doing a runtime load of a module while also expecting the symbols for that module to exist at compile time." The `require Foo::Bar` statement means that *one* symbol *is* brought into existence at compile-time, namely `Foo::Bar`. And that's the only symbol that's being *explicitly* assumed (though `.new` is expected to work). So the compiler of course doesn't complain. Although the error message makes perfect sense when you know what's going on here it is, imo, LTA. Perhaps there would best be another repr that's a variant of the Uninstantiable one that yields a more helpful message?

Answer (score 5):

I think it's because [require](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/require) is a runtime load whereas [use](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/use) is compile time.

Generally I'd use `use` unless I have a need for dynamic module loading at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

`use` loads and imports a module at compile-time while `require` only loads a module at runtime.

Since the namespace is checked at compile-time, you can't just access it as you would a module that is loaded and imported with `use`.

You can get around that by symbolic references, but you can also capture the namespace into a variable.
(Assuming there is only a single namespace in the module, and it is the same as the name used to load it)

**Foo.pm6**:

```perl6
unit module Foo;

sub fubar () { say 'fubar' }
```

```perl6
my \Foo = do require Foo;
Foo::fubar(); # fubar␤
```

(Note that the name of the variable doesn't have to be the same.)