# Behaviour of require (static + dynamic) [ RAKU ]

Tags: require, lookup, raku, rakudo

My question is related to the behaviour of **require** when used with static or dynamic resolution of the desired namespace.

I'll try to present my understanding of things:

**[ 1 ] Use "require" with a literal**

```
    { require MODULE; }
```

In this case the compiler checks to see if MODULE has already been declared as a symbol. 
If it hasn't, the compiler declares it, and binds it to an empty placeholder package it's just created for this "require"

```
{
    my $response = ::('MODULE');  # this happens at runtime
    say $response.^name;          # MODULE doesn't exist so the lookup results in the compilation-phase placeholder package: MODULE

    try require MODULE;           # although the execution order of require comes after the lookup, 
                                  # the placeholder package creation was done during compilation and the package is present in the current scope during run-time
}
```

**[ 2 ] Use "require" with a String**

```
    { try require 'FILE_PATH'; }
```

In this case "require" is trying to find (at run-time) a file that is defined by the filename declared in the string. 
If found (with appropriate content: modules, packages etc.) then it creates a namespace(s) in the current scope and loads it with the content(s) of the file.

**[ 3 ] Use "require" with a dynamic lookup**

```
    { try require ::('MODULE'); }
```

It seems to me that in that case "require" behaves **NOT** as a "normal" subroutine.

When we use "require" with "dynamic lookup" then the core functionality of the dynamic lookup is "melted" in a new routine that behaves differently than we would expect.

The fact is that the result of the "dynamic lookup" routine is either a symbol or a Failure.

If "require" behaves like a "normal" subroutine, then the only input it could use, would be the result of the dynamic lookup that followed it (Namespace or Failure).

But it is also a fact that in the case of a Failure (as the result of dynamic lookup), "require" continues searching the repositories for a proper package (as is normally the case, using nevertheless the argument we gave to dynamic lookup: 'MODULE').

So obviously "require" isn't behaving like a "normal" subroutine in that sense.

As the result of my line of thought the combination of require + dynamic lookup resembles the following construct:

```
{ modified_dynamic_lookup('MODULE') :if_symbol_not_found_search_repositories_and_if_appropriate_package_found_create_namespace_and_load_package_contents; }
```

My concern is my understanding of case [3].

How does require + dynamic lookup work? (analytically speaking - what are the steps followed by the compiler at first and then by the runtime?)

**[ Post Scriptum ]**

I agree with @raiph that "require" is **NOT** a subroutine and that it is deeply integrated in the language.

In that sense the "dynamic lookup construct" that follows the require "instruction" is used for 2 things:

1. To notify the compiler that the construct is "dynamic" (so don't
   bother fixing anything at compile time)
2. To provide the string that will be used to search for symbols,
       namespaces, files or repository content

@raiph states that he thinks that "require" does a lookup after a successful load.

My only objection about that is that when we load the same library "require" doesn't throw any exception.

Is it silently ignoring the loaded library? 
Why bother doing so much work when it can check first that the same namespace is already in use?

In contrary when we pretend that we load a different library then it throws an Exception : "duplicate definition" of the symbol in use.

To demostrate that I conducted the following:

In ./lib directory I place two libraries, the "foo.pm6" which is a unit definition of "foo" with a class A defined in it:

```
file "foo.pm6" contents:
-----------------------------------
unit module foo;

class A is export {}
```

and another library "other.pm6" that has inside a definition of "foo" this time with a different class B defined in it.

```
file "other.pm6" contents:
-----------------------------------
module foo {
    class B is export {}
}
```

The raku program file contains the following:

```
use lib <lib>;

my $name = 'other';           # select one of {'other', 'foo'}

require ::('foo') <A>;        ########> Initial package loading

my $a = try ::('foo::A').new;
say '(1) ' ~ $a.^name;        # (1) foo::A

$a = ::('A').new;
say '(2) ' ~ $a.^name;        # (2) foo::A

try require ::($name);        # if $name eq 'other' => throws exception, if $name eq 'foo' => does nothing
with $! {.say};               # P6M Merging GLOBAL symbols failed: duplicate definition of symbol foo ...

$a = try ::('foo::A').new;
say '(3) ' ~ $a.^name;        # (3) foo::A

$a = ::('A').new;
say '(4) ' ~ $a.^name;        # (4) foo::A
```

From the example above we see that when we try to reload the foo namespace, hidden in a file with a different name (just to trick raku) it throws an exception.

Therefore I conclude that maybe "require" checks first for a namespace that has the same name as the provided string.

By the way, checking about this, I stumbled upon a strange behaviour. It's the following:

If we use "use foo;" in line: "Initial package loading" instead of "require ::('foo') ;", we get the following results:

```
(1) foo::A
(2) foo::A
No such symbol 'other' ...

(3) Any
(4) foo::A
```

The lookup of 'foo::A' in (3) doesn't find anything !!!

Furthermore if I change the library file: "other.pm6" with the following (class A instead of B - as in the foo.pm6)

```
file "other.pm6" contents:
-----------------------------------
module foo {
    class A is export {}
}
```

the result seem to revert to the expected:

```
(1) foo::A
(2) foo::A
No such symbol 'other' ...

(3) foo::A
(4) foo::A
```

Is it a bug or something else that I'm missing?

Comment: I have not read your question, but have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56089611/what-could-be-the-reason-that-require-doesnt-work-in-some-places/56090265#56090265? Is your question essentially a duplicate of it?

Comment: Yes I have! But my question doesn't have to do (at least not at first glance) with the resulting implications of the use of the one or the other way. I understand the use of both ways (static and dynamic). It is more about the "if" and "how" the "require" statement is not a normal subroutine but rather a transformative agent of the dynamic lookup. It is only a matter of confirmation of my understanding of things.

Comment: Your example is wrong. You don't get a `Failure`. From [`require`'s doc](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules#index-entry-require): "Note that the placeholder will be kept, even if require failed to load the module."

Comment: I was refering to the response of the dynamic lookup: { my $response = ::('EXAMPLE'); } A Failure is returned if the lookup failed!

Comment: Ok. Understood. :) But your example in your question is still wrong. When I work thru questions, one of the first things I do is to load example code and run it. If it doesn't do what the questioner says it does, that's confusing. Your code reflects your confusion. If you wrote `{ my $foo = ::('EXAMPLE'); try require EXAMPLE }` you might get insight into this. In the mean time, please consider revising your example code, or rather the comments, to make sense to readers. TIA.

Comment: "although the execution order of `require` comes after the lookup". That's not correct. The order of execution of code does not necessarily follow the human reading order. As a general point, all code in Raku is subject to both phases, and phase shifting. As a specific point, `require` is a statement, and some of its behavior is executed during the overall compile phase, which comes first, and some during the overall run phase, which comes later. The execution of the compile phase aspects of the `require` occur *before* the execution of the run phase aspects of the lookup.

Comment: If you wrote `BEGIN { my $response = ::('MODULE'); say $response.^name }` then you'd phase shift the code in braces to execute during the compile phase, and it would execute *before* the compile phase aspects of the `require`, so it would display `Failure`. "MODULE doesn't exist so the lookup results in the compilation-phase placeholder package: MODULE" I think that reflects your confusion. MODULE *does* exist in your example code. Your `say...` is executed *after* the `require MODULE` has executed its compile phase behavior, part of which was to declare the `MODULE` symbol.

Comment: "If found (with appropriate content: modules, packages etc.) then it creates a namespace(s) in the current scope and loads it with the content(s) of the file." It doesn't create a namespace if the symbol has already been declared. This is true no matter which `require` variant is used. See the example at the end of my answer.

Comment: "It seems to me that in that case "require" behaves NOT as a "normal" subroutine." It is NOT a subroutine. It's a *keyword* in Raku's *grammar*. The parser spots the *specific* 7 character string "require", just as it might spot the specific 8 character string `::('foo')`, and parses it as per the grammar, generates AST code as per the Raku grammar's associated actions class, codegens from that to a backend, eg to MoarVM bytecode which gets run on the MoarVM backend. Yes, the code generated corresponding to `require` includes function calls; no, `require` is not a routine *at all*.

Comment: "in the case of a `Failure` (as the result of dynamic lookup), "require" continues searching the repositories for a proper package" I think you are wrong. "How does require + dynamic lookup work? (analytically speaking - what are the steps followed by the compiler at first and then by the runtime?)" My answer includes a high level look at the exact compiler code, including a glimpse into the generated AST. My tests of `require`'s behavior, and my (admittedly brief) review of the code generated by a `require`, suggest to me it does not do a lookup until *after* the package has been loaded.

Comment: I've rewritten my answer to precisely match the third version of your question. Please be assured I have read every word you've written, again. and have considered it all carefully, and have run all your code, and explored it, and so forth. Please read at least the Post Scriptum section. If you disagree with any of it please consider *not* starting writing comments, or changing your question, before taking a long break, perhaps a week, and then making sure you run each of the code examples I provide, and then read my entire answer carefully, *before* comments/edits/additions. TIA. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewritten to correspond to [the third version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62131486/3) of your answer.

## [ 1 ] Use "require" with a literal

> In this case the compiler checks to see if `MODULE` has already been declared as a symbol. If it hasn't, the compiler declares it, and binds it to an empty placeholder package it's just created for this "require"

To be a bit more specific, the `require` *keyword*, and the code generated by it<sup>4</sup>, does the work.

And the only reason it's created the symbol is so that one can write that identifier and the code will compile. If `require` didn't do that then code that uses the identifier would fail to compile even if the `require FOO` would have succeeded:

```
require FOO;
my FOO $bar; # Type 'FOO' is not declared
```

> # MODULE doesn't exist so the lookup results in the compilation-phase placeholder package: MODULE

`MODULE` *does* exist. And the lookup succeeds. It returns the value bound to the `MODULE` symbol, which is the placeholder package that `require` put there during the compilation phase.

> # although the execution order of `require` comes after the lookup

The execution of `require`'s compilation-phase actions came *before* the lookup which happens during the run phase.

## [ 2 ] Use "require" with a String**

> If found (with appropriate content: modules, packages etc.) then it creates a namespace(s) in the current scope and loads it with the content(s) of the file.

I think the only declaration of symbols `require` does is the ones the code writer has explicitly written as static identifiers as part of the `require` statement. Examples:

- `require MODULE <A>;`       --> `MODULE` and `A`.
- `require 'MODULE.pm6' <A>;` --> `A`.
- `require ::('MODULE') <A>;` --> `A`.

Aiui the MLS<sup>1</sup>, as part of symbol *merging* (P6M), declares further symbols as necessary. But this work isn't being done by *`require`*. It's done by MLS on its behalf. And it isn't peculiar to `require`. It's the same (sort of) work that happens during the compile-phase as a result of a `use` statement.

## [ 3 ] Use "require" with a dynamic lookup

```
{ try require ::('MODULE'); }
```

I have code that is an attempt to demonstrate that this does *not* do a lookup before attempting to load the module.<sup>2</sup>

> It seems to me that in that case "require" behaves NOT as a "normal" subroutine.

`require` is not a routine, normal or otherwise.

```
say require MODULE;   # Undeclared name:
                            MODULE used at line 1
                      # Undeclared routine:
                            require used at line 1
```

If you search for `require` in [the official doc](https://docs.raku.org/) you'll see it's *not* listed in the **Routine Reference** section but rather the Modules part of the **Language Reference**. It's a keyword, a statement, a special part of the language that the compiler understands.

> If "require" behaves like a "normal" subroutine, then the only input it could use, would be the result of the dynamic lookup that followed it (Namespace or Failure).

The result of a dynamic lookup is the value bound to a [Symbol](https://docs.raku.org/language/glossary#index-entry-Symbol), if it's declared, or `Failure` otherwise:

```
my $variable = 42;
say ::('$variable');           # 42
say ::('nonsense') ~~ Failure; # True
```

`$variable` is not a Namespace.

> But it is also a fact that in the case of a Failure (as the result of dynamic lookup), "require" continues searching the repositories for a proper package (as is normally the case, using nevertheless the argument we gave to dynamic lookup: 'MODULE').

Given the code I wrote tracking dynamic lookup of the value of ::('MODULE')<sup>2</sup> it looks likely to me that there is no dynamic lookup of it by any code, whether `require` or the MLS, if the module loading *fails*.

That in turn implies that it only happens, if at all, *during or after* (successful) loading of a module. So either the MLS is doing it (seems most likely), or, perhaps, `require` is doing it *after* the module has been successfully loaded (seems unlikely but I'm not yet ready to 100% eliminate it).

`{ modified_dynamic_lookup('MODULE') :if_symbol_not_found_search_repositories_and_if_appropriate_package_found_create_namespace_and_load_package_contents; }`

I think I've proven that there is either no lookup at all by `require` or the MLS, or, if it does it, it's only *after* a module has been successfully loaded.

> what are the steps followed by the compiler at first and then by the runtime?

This answer is of course an attempt to answer that but my brief compiler code analysis may be of some help.<sup>3</sup> (Though clicking the link to see the actual code in `Actions.nqp` is not for the faint of heart!)

## [ Post Scriptum ]

> In that sense the "dynamic lookup construct" that follows the require "instruction" is used for 2 things:
>
> 1. To notify the compiler that the construct is "dynamic" (so don't bother fixing anything at compile time)
> 2. To provide the string that will be used to search for symbols, namespaces, files or repository content

I think it only does 2, just a package name that's passed to the MLS.

> when we load the same library "require" doesn't throw any exception. Is it silently ignoring the loaded library?

I don't think `require` knows anything about it. It hands it off to the MLS and then picks up after the MLS has done its thing. I don't think `require` can tell the difference between when MLS does a successful fresh load and when it just skips the load. All it knows is whether MLS says all is good or there's an exception.

> Why bother doing so much work when it can check first that the same namespace is already in use?

Why bother doing *any* work when the MLS already does it, and `require` is going to invoke the MLS anyway? Doing *anything* is wasted effort.

All `require` has to do is deal with the *compile-phase* symbols the user has explicitly typed in the `require` statement. It *can't* ask the MLS to deal with those because it's got nothing to do with a *successful* module load, and that's the only scenario in which the MLS goes fiddling with symbols.

> In contrary when we pretend that we load a different library then it throws an Exception : "duplicate definition" of the symbol in use.

Try this:

```
require ::('foo');
require ::('other');
```

Now try it again when you change the `unit module foo;` in `foo.pm6` and `other.pm6` to `unit module bar;`. You'll still get the same exception, but the symbol will be `bar`. How can `require` know about `bar`? It can't. The exception is coming from the MLS and the symbol is only known about by the MLS.

> Therefore I conclude that maybe "require" checks first for a namespace that has the same name as the provided string.

Unless you count the MLS as part of `require`, I trust you can now see that your "maybe" qualification was wise. :)

> I stumbled upon a strange behaviour ... The lookup of 'foo::A' in (3) doesn't find anything !!!

I've got an explanation for that. I'm not saying it's right, but it doesn't seem *too* strange to me as I write this:

The `use` statement loads the `foo.pm6` package. It defines a package `foo`, which contains a class `A`, and exports `A`. That results in a symbol in the importing lexical scope `foo`, which is bound to a package, which package contains a symbol `A`. It also results in another symbol in the importing lexical scope, `A`.

The `require` statement loads the `other.pm6` package. It defines a package `foo`, which contains a class `B`, and exports `B`. That results in rebinding the `foo` symbol in the importing lexical scope to a different package, namely the new package containing the symbol `B`. It also results in another symbol in the importing lexical scope, `B`.

The earlier `A` hangs around. (In other words the P6M symbol merging process doesn't include *removing* symbols.) But `foo::A`, which is looked up in the package bound to the `foo` symbol, no longer exists, because the package bound to the `foo` symbol is now the one from the `other.pm6` package, having overwritten the one from the `foo.pm6` package.

In the meantime there's another oddity:

```
try require ::($name);
with $! {.say};             # No such symbol 'other' ...
```

I think this reflects `require` doing a (failed) lookup *after* a *successful* module load.

Note that this message does *not* appear if the module fails to load; this seems to again confirm my thinking (and code<sup>2</sup>) that `require` does not do any lookup until after a successful load (if that; I still don't have a strong sense about whether it's the MLS that's doing this stuff or the `require`; the code<sup>4</sup> is too complex for me atm).

## Responses to your comments

From your comments on this answer:

> Its like we get as the result of the amalgamation of require + 'dynamic lookup formulation' an enhanced dynamic lookup like this `{ ::('something') :if_not_found_as_namespace_check_repositories_and_load }`

That doesn't ring true for me for various reasons.

For example, presume there's a package `foo` declared as `module foo { our sub bar is export { say 99 } }` that will successfully load if `require`d. Now consider this code:

```
my \foo = 42;
say ::('foo');             # 42
require ::('foo') <&bar>;
say foo;                   # 42
bar;                       # 99
```

This makes sense to me. It won't have loaded a package whose name is`42`. It won't have looked up the symbol `foo`. It will have loaded the package whose name is `foo`. And while it presumably will have looked up symbol `foo` *after* loading the package, it *won't* have installed a symbol `foo` because there's already one.

## Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> By *Module Loading Subsystem* I mean the various parts that, given a module name, do things like searching the local file system, or a database, checking precompilation directories, invoking compilation, and merging symbols if a module successfully loads. I don't know where the boundaries are between the parts, and the parts and the compiler. But I'm confident they are *not* part of `require` but merely invoked by it.

---

<sup>2</sup> Run this code:

```
my \MODULE =
  { my $v;
    Proxy.new:
      FETCH => method { say "get name: $v"; $v },
      STORE => method ($n) { say "set name: $n"; $v = $n }}();

MODULE = 'unseen by `require`';
say ::('MODULE');

use lib '.';
say 'about to `require`';
require ::('MODULE');
```

---

<sup>3</sup> We start with [the relevant match in Raku's `Grammar.nqp` file](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/62adc88c69ab2532db11c573b3ccb0452811a14c/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L1363-L1371):

```
  rule statement_control:sym<require> {
        <sym>
        [
        | <module_name>
        | <file=.variable>
        | <!sigil> <file=.term>
        ]
        <EXPR>?
    }
```

The code seems to follow what we expect -- a `require` keyword followed by either:

- a package identifier (`<module_name>`); or
- a `<variable>` (eg `$foo`); or
- a `<term>` that doesn't start with a `<sigil>`.

We're interested in the `<module_name>` branch. It calls `token module_name` which calls `token longname` which calls `token name`:

```
token name {
        [
        | <identifier> <morename>*
        | <morename>+
        ]
}
```

Clearly `::('foo')` doesn't begin with an `<identifier>`. So it's [`token morename`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/62adc88c69ab2532db11c573b3ccb0452811a14c/src/Perl6/Grammar.nqp#L579-L591). I'll cut out a few uninteresting lines to leave:

```
    token morename {
        '::'
        [
        ||  <?before '(' | <.alpha> >
            [
            | <identifier>
            | :dba('indirect name') '(' ~ ')' [ <.ws> <EXPR> ]
            ]
        ]?
    }
```

Bingo. That'll match `::(`, in particular the `:dba('indirect name') '(' ~ ')' [ <.ws> <EXPR> ]` bit.

So at this point we'll have captured:

```
statement_control:sym<require><module_name><longname><name><morename><EXPR>
```

A short while later the `statement_control:sym<require>` token will be about to succeed. So at that point it will call the corresponding action method in `Actions.nqp`...

---

<sup>4</sup> In `Actions.nqp` we find the action corresponding to `token statement_control:sym<require>`, namely [`method statement_control:sym<require>`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/62adc88c69ab2532db11c573b3ccb0452811a14c/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp#L2143-L2274). The opening `if $<module_name> {` conditional will be `True`, leading to running this code:

```
$longname := $*W.dissect_longname($<module_name><longname>);
$target_package := $longname.name_past;
```

It looks to me like this code is dissecting the result of parsing `::('foo')`, and binding AST corresponding to that dissection to `$target_package`, rather than bothering to do a lookup or prepare a run-time lookup.

If I'm right, the `::('foo')` does not need to be anything more than 9 characters that `require` gets to interpret however it fancies interpreting them. There's no necessary implication here it does any particular thing, such as a lookup, as it constructs the package loading code.

---

The latter half of the action *does* do lookups. There are lines like [this](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/62adc88c69ab2532db11c573b3ccb0452811a14c/src/Perl6/Actions.nqp#L2267):

```
?? self.make_indirect_lookup($longname.components())
```

and given the routine name I presume that that *is* doing a lookup, perhaps as part of where `require` attempts to add a package symbol if the package load succeeds.

Comment: What about my last paragraph ! Is that also the way require + dynamic lookup works?

Comment: @jakar I've added your last paragraphs and my response. PLMK if you agree with them, or specify which version of Rakudo you're using if not. Thanks.

Comment: I'm very sorry about my chopped explanation! What i meant is the following: The require-enhanced "dynamic lookup" makes a normal lookup and in case there are no findings proceeds by making a "search" in the raku modules repositories and if found there, loads it, otherwise throws an exception. The depiction i wanted to make is about the different behaviour of the plain dynamic lookup routine, that doesn't bother looking further into the repositories (checks only the namespaces)...

Comment: ... The difference in behaviour might look minor to someone but I was concerned by the fact that the require statement (that is presented as subroutine call) alters the behaviour of the upcomming subroutine (dynamic lookup).

Comment: If you have the patience, please reread my answer (I've heavily edited it) and comment on any mistakes or confusing bits. Perhaps we can narrow things down to a small number of remaining confusing bits. And maybe you can then edit your question and/or I can (at least temporarily) delete this answer, and/or offer a bonus to try get a good answer.

Comment: Imported symbols need to be declared at compile time too.

Comment: The part that you wrote: But in require ::('jakar'), I'm not convinced ::('jakar') is a dynamic lookup... is what i was trying to formulate in my writings. It seems to me that the combination of require + dynamic lookup is NOT the sum of their parts but something new that has somewhat alternated behaviour. The dynamic lookup on its own checks about a symbol and if not found returns a Failure. The combination on the other hand continues after the failure and more specifically "require" uses the argument ('jakar') of the "dynamic lookup" subroutine in order to check further in the repositories.

Comment: Its like we get as the result of the amalgamation of require + 'dynamic lookup formulation' an enhanced dynamic lookup like this { ::('something') :if_not_found_as_namespace_check_repositories_and_load }

Comment: I revised my whole post! Please if you have time take a look at it.

Comment: Heh. I've revised my whole answer. I suggest you look at the very last bit that quotes your comment just above and provides a code example. Then consider looking at the compiler code spelunking I did. In the meantime I'll go read your question revision.

Comment: @jjmerelo Thanks. I've added that to my answer.

Comment: @raiph Thanks for your time and effort! From a small glimpse at your revised answer I think that it will cover my questions. I'll return later to dedicate more time for a more complete analysis of your explanations.

Comment: @raiph I revised my post and added a "Post Scriptum" section. In general I agree about your findings.Please give it a read if you have time to do so! Anyway, I appreciate your effort and the way you are scrutinize things!

Comment: @raiph I agree with your comments. What should we do with the odd behaviours? Open a ticket ?

Comment: I think perceived "oddness" is due to our lack of familiarity with the behavior, not actual problems with Raku(do). So imo priority #1 is to try confirm or reject our explanations thru further experiment/analysis. I think my explanations of the oddities I still see may be correct. In which case it would be best if no tickets were opened, or maybe just doc ones. Before that, we should scour existing doc, SOs, issue queues, etc. and do more experiments/analysis. Then, if anything remains unresolved a week from now, write new SOs with code, and with no speculation, one SO per narrow question.

Answer (score 2):

`require` does some things during compilation if it can.

```raku
require Module;
say Module;
```

It assumes that loading that module will give you something with the name of `Module`.

So it installs a temporary symbol with that name at compile time.

That is the only thing it does at compile time.
(So I fibbed when I said “some things”.)

```raku
if Bool.pick {
    require module-which-does-not-exist;

    module-which-does-not-exist.method-call()
}
```

About half of the time the above does nothing.
The other half of the time it complains at run-time that it can't find the module.

(I chose `Bool.pick` instead of `False` so the compile-time optimizer definitely can't optimize it away.)

---

When you call it with something other than an identifier, it doesn't know at compile-time what the module will be.
So it can't create a temporary namespace.

```raku
require 'Module';
say Module; # COMPILE ERROR: undeclared name
```

```raku
require Module; # RUNTIME ERROR: can't find 'Module'
say Module;
```

```raku
require 'Module'; # RUNTIME ERROR: can't find 'Module'
say ::('Module');
```

```raku
if False {
    require Module;
    say Module;
}
# no error at all
```

```raku
if False {
    require 'Module';
    say ::('Module');
}
# no error at all
```